Setting AuthClientConfig from Ngrx Store effects not reflecting in AuthService
I am using angular-18 in stand alone mode with ngrx,
I am trying to load configuration using ngrx store and then initialize the auth0 related parameters .
Even though I am configuring the AuthClientConfig before calling authService.loginWithRedirect, it take the values provided from app.config.ts file (empty values for redirect uri)
Please help me to load the values from configuration file to auth0 client config.
app.config.ts

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideStore(),
    provideEffects(),
    provideEffects([ConfigEffects, AuthEffects]), // Register the effects
    provideStore({ config: configReducer, auth: authReducer }), // Register the reducer
    provideStoreDevtools({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideAuth0({
      domain: '',  // Placeholder, will be replaced by NgRx config
      clientId: '',  // Placeholder, will be replaced by NgRx config
    }),
  ]
};






config.effects.ts -> This is how I load my configurations
@Injectable()
export class ConfigEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private authClientConfig: AuthClientConfig,
    private store: Store // Inject the Store
  ) {}

  loadConfig$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ConfigActions.loadConfig),
      mergeMap(() =>
        from(this.configService.loadConfig()).pipe(
          map(() => {
            const config = this.configService.appConfig;
            return ConfigActions.loadConfigSuccess({ config });
          }),
          catchError((error) => of(ConfigActions.loadConfigFailure({ error }))))
      )
    )
  );

  // Effect to initialize Auth0 after configuration is loaded
initAuthConfig$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ConfigActions.loadConfigSuccess),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectAuthConfig)), // Fetch auth0 config from the store
    concatMap(([action, config]) => {
      if (config) {
        console.log('config', config);
        
        // Set the Auth0 config dynamically from the store
        this.authClientConfig.set({
          domain: config.domain,
          clientId: config.clientId,
          errorPath: '/auth/access-denied',
          authorizationParams: {
            redirect_uri: config.redirectUri,
            audience: config.audience
          },
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Auth0 config not found in store');
      }

      // Dispatch the initAuthConfigComplete action only after setting the config
      return of(ConfigActions.initAuthConfigComplete());
    })
  )
);
}


auth.effects.ts --> authentication related functions
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects { 
  
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthService,) {}

  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(login),
      mergeMap(() => {
        return this.authService.user$.pipe(
          map(user => {
            return loginSuccess({ user: user as AuthUser });  // Dispatch loginSuccess with user data, updated to AuthUser
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            return of(loginFailure({ error }));
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );

  loadUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loadUser),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.authService.user$.pipe(
          map(user => loginSuccess({ user: user as AuthUser })),
          catchError(error => of(loginFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    )
  );
  redirectToLogin$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(redirectToLogin),
      tap(action => {
        this.authService.loginWithRedirect({
          appState: { target: action.target } // Redirect to the target URL after login
        });
      })
    ),
    { dispatch: false } // No need to dispatch a new action after redirection
  );

}


